# Trouble with Wordpress and GSAP TweenLite

Tags: php, wordpress, gsap

I'm in the process of creating my first WordPress theme and I'm trying to integrate the TweenLite library but it's not working. I'm not sure where the error lies.

First in my child theme's function.php file I have:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_scripts');

function custom_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('GSAP', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js', true);
    wp_register_script('Animations', get_template_directory_uri() . '/animation.js', true);
}
```

The first script is the TweenLite and the second is my custom script I'm using test out of it worked or not.

This is my code for my test script:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
TweenLite.to(logo, 1.5, { width: 500 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wp_register_script is not enough.
You must enqueue it after registering with wp_enqueue_script();

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_scripts');

function custom_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('GSAP','http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js', true);
    wp_register_script('Animations', get_template_directory_uri() . '/animation.js', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('GSAP');
    wp_enqueue_script('Animations');
}
```

Comment: Do I enqueue it inside the function or outside?